# I confused with trigonometry. $\sin x - \cos x = 1$

Tags: trigonometry

I got confused with trigonometry.I think that my way which I tried to solve is ok because I don't understand what I just did wrong.

$\sin x - \cos x = 1$

$\sin x - 1 = \cos x$

$\sin x - 1 = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2(x)} \rightarrow$ Now I think that I can square both sides, but before that I find definitions for $x$ :
$f(x) = g(x); g(x) \geq 0$  so  $'f(x)'$ also must be greater or equal $0$.

```
         f(x)>=0 ==> [sinx - 1 >= 0]

                     [sinx >= 1] ==> x=90°
```

$[1 - \sin^2(x) \geq 0]$

$[\sin^2(x) \leq 1]$

$[\sin^2(x) - 1 \leq 0]$

$[(\sin x - 1)(\sin x + 1) \leq 0]$

$(\sin x - 1 \leq 0) \Rightarrow **x=90°** x \in [0°,180°]$

$(\sin x + 1 \leq 0) ==> **x=270°** x \in [180°,360°]$

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlwSd.png

So what I have done, it just bring me confusion...

Help me guys with this trigonometry..

Comment: Claiming that $\cos x= \sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$ is wrong. A byproduct of this is that, when you apply the *correct* procedure of discussing the sign of $A$ in $A=\sqrt B$, you *should* end up losing part of the solutions.

Comment: How? If $sin^2x + cos^2x = 1 -> cosx = √(1- sin^2x)$

Comment: Since when does $A^2=B$ imply $A=\sqrt B$? That's never been a thing.

Comment: 1. Follow some of the links that show you how to use MathJax better. Your formulas are still not very easy to read. 2. Explain _in words_ what you did in each step. Just writing a formula is usually not enough. 3. What is the point of the image you linked to?

Comment: $$\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x} = \sqrt{\cos^2 x} = \pm \cos x$$  or, $\cos x = \pm \sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}$  You can't restrict $\cos x$ to only $+\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}$, which is what you did here.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site using MathJax.

Comment: Use `$\leq$` for $\leq$.

Comment: How is $a-1 =\sqrt{1-a^2}$ in the third step correct algebraically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\sin{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\cos{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$ or
$$\sin\left(x-45^{\circ}\right)=\sin45^{\circ},$$
which gives $$x-45^{\circ}=45^{\circ}+360^{\circ}k,$$ where $k$ is an integer number, or
$$x-45^{\circ}=135^{\circ}+360^{\circ}k,$$ which gives the answer:
$$\left\{90^{\circ}+360^{\circ}k,180^{\circ}+360^{\circ}k|,k\in\mathbb Z\right\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**just a hint**

$$\sin(x)=1+\cos(x)$$ becomes

$$2\sin(\frac x2)\cos(\frac x2)=2\cos(\frac x2)\cos(\frac x2)$$

thus
$$\cos(x/2)=0$$ or
$$\sin(x/2)=\cos(x/2)=\sin(\pi/2-x/2)$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sin x -\cos x = 1$

Squaring both sides we get:

$\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x -2 \sin x \cos x=1$

⇒$- \sin 2x= 0 = \sin 4k\pi+\pi$

⇒ $x=(4k+1) \frac{\pi}{2}$; $k ∈ N$

Or $x = (2k+1)\pi $; $k ∈ N$

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy way to solve this problem. Since we have
$$ \sin x - \cos x = 1 $$
Then we can square both sides to obtain
$$ \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x - 2\sin x \cos x = 1$$
So by the Pythagorean identity means
$$ 2\sin x \cos x = 0 $$
Or
$$ \sin 2x = 0.$$
From here I think you know what to do.